# QEMU Windows guest without internet but with a shared folder

Tags: networking, firewall, qemu

I'm setting up a Debian machine running a Windows 7 guest in a qemu/kvm virtualization stack. Since the Windows machine is running out-dated software, I decided to put it into a VM without Internet access. However, I need to get files in and out of the VM.

I heard that it's possible to set up a host-only network and change the firewall rules in order to prohibit all accesses but to the host machine. The host however needs full Internet access.

I have no experience with firewall configuration under Linux. How can I achieve the goal described above?

Answer (score 4):

This should do it:

```
$ qemu-system-x86_64 -net nic -net user,restrict=on,smb=/path/to/shared/folder ...
```

From the [manpage](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/qemu-system-common/qemu-system.1.en.html):

> ```
> -netdev user,id=id[,option][,option][,...]
> -net user[,option][,option][,...]
>     Use the user mode network stack which requires no administrator
>     privilege to run. Valid options are:
>     ...
>     restrict=on|off
>         If this option is enabled, the guest will be isolated, i.e. it
>         will not be able to contact the host and no guest IP packets
>         will be routed over the host to the outside. This option does
>         not affect any explicitly set forwarding rules.
>     ...              
>     smb=dir[,smbserver=addr]
>         When using the user mode network stack, activate a built-in SMB
>         server so that Windows OSes can access to the host files in dir
>         transparently. The IP address of the SMB server can be set to
>         addr. By default the 4th IP in the guest network is used, i.e.
>         x.x.x.4.
>         In the guest Windows OS, the line:
>                 10.0.2.4 smbserver
>         must be added in the file C:\WINDOWS\LMHOSTS (for windows
>         9x/Me) or C:\WINNT\SYSTEM32\DRIVERS\ETC\LMHOSTS (Windows
>         NT/2000).
>         Then dir can be accessed in \\smbserver\qemu.
>         Note that a SAMBA server must be installed on the host OS.
>         QEMU was tested successfully with smbd versions from Red Hat 9,
>         Fedora Core 3 and OpenSUSE 11.x.
> ```

For this to work, `samba` must be installed on the host system; it doesn't need to be configured or running, just the `smbd` binary is needed, which will be run with an ad-hoc configuration and no privileges.

**Note**

In windows 7, you can connect to the shared folder from
Computer -> Add Network Location -> Choose a custom network location -> \\10.0.2.4\qemu.

If windows insists on opening the "Connect to the Internet" wizard, then just close it; the "Add Network Location" wizard is still running, and you can reopen its window by clicking on the taskbar icon.

Comment: Is possible to do it in graphical virt-manager?

Comment: @lucky62 I haven't tried it, but probably yes if virt-manager lets you add custom arguments to the qemu command line. But I don't see the point of it -- this is about running an isolated windows instance, not one connected to any virtual network.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, I can use virt-manager to create an isolated network, then start up samba (smb server) and configure it to listen to virbr1 (the isolated network). Appearently the isolated network prohibits communication to the outside world but allows to reach the host, which is exactly what I was looking for.

EDIT for more explanation:

- For creating an isolated network, refer to https://wiki.libvirt.org/page/VirtualNetworking#Isolated_mode and https://wiki.libvirt.org/page/VirtualNetworking#Isolated_mode_2
- Use `ip addr` (or simimlar) on the host to find out the host's IP address for the new network bridge
- Additionally, you may configure the guest's IP settings to get a static IP
- Then simply use the host's and guest's IPs for communication
- For more info about setting up samba, check out the official documentation or a tutorial such as https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/install-and-configure-samba#0

Comment: I want to do the same exact thing. Can you please post more details about how to do this?

Comment: I elaborated in an edit, hope that helps