# QEMU: Enable SFTP file exchange (guest ⇆ host) but prohibit guests access to public internet?

Tags: virtual-machine, qemu, sftp, file-transfer, virt-manager

Assumed I run a Windows guest in a `QEMU` virtual machine on a Debian host. Hereby the Debian host is a common desktop computer with internet access.

How can I set up a `SFTP` file exchange between guest and host **but prevent the guest** (= Windows) **from accessing the internet?**

1. Set up a Virtual Network Interface (NIC) for the belonging Windows machine in `virt-manager` (default setting is network `NAT` with device `virtio`)
2. Install network driver in guest machine (Windows)
3. Install WinSCP in the guest machine (Windows)

But what then? Where can I prevent public internet access only for this guest? Is this already possible in `virt-manager` without messing up the host firewall?

Several other guest machines should not be affected by this.

Comment: Give the guest OS an IP and a route to your regular network (specific subnet), but not a default gateway. Or if you use a "bridged" type connection just giving it an IP but no default gateway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new virtual network in virt-manager with its connectivity set to **Isolated virtual network**.

[image: Isolated virtual network]

In this configuration, VMs on this network can only access other VMs on the same network and the host (using only the host's IP address for the isolated network).

Answer (score 2):

I don't use `virtmanager`, but with plain `qemu` that's very simple:

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -net nic -net "user,restrict=on,guestfwd=:10.0.2.1:22-cmd:netcat 127.0.0.1 22,hostfwd=::2222-:22" -enable-kvm   ...  -m 4G -hda windows.qcow2
```

That's using "user mode" (slirp) networking with the "restrict" mode on, and does some forwardings.

To connect with `ssh`/`scp`/`sftp` from the host to the guest, you use `ssh -p 2222 localhost` and `scp -P 2222 from_file localhost:to_file`.

To connect from the guest to the host, you use `ssh 10.0.2.1` (or set `10.0.2.1` as the host in whatever dialog box of `putty` or `winscp`)

For the `restrict=on` flag, have a look at my answer [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/451306/qemu-windows-guest-without-internet-but-with-a-shared-folder/469200#469200). That may be closer to what you really need than `scp` or `sftp`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! About `restrict=on` the manual says: `If this option is enabled, the guest will be isolated, i.e. it will not be able to contact the host and no guest IP packets will be routed over the host to the outside. This option does not affect any explicitly set forwarding rules.` - That would explicitely claim that network access to the host is not possible anymore as well, no? Or did we already adjust the forwarding rules with the upper part? :-)

Comment: Exactly, except for the forwardings you set explicitly. If you want to give the guest complete access to the host, but not to anything beyond that, you cannot do it without modifying the firewall rules on the host.

Comment: I'm not sure I undestand what 'upper part' you're talking about, but in the man page "forwardings" refer to those set with the `guestfwd` and `hostfwd` options of `qemu`, not to forwardings set with eg. `iptables` on the host.

Comment: With "upper part" I mean the executable command in your answer including the forwarding rules. :-)

Comment: The order of the `restrict=`,`guestfwd=`,`hostfwd=` suboptions of `-net user` does not matter, if that's what you're alluding to.

Comment: @Dave so, have you tried it? what/why didn't work?

Comment: I am so sorry, I have never used `qemu` via CLI... :-( Can I edit `qemu` guest machine settings based on your command still after setting up the machine within `virt-manager`? Or do I have to create a completely new machine for this, purely in CLI?

Comment: You can try using the disk image of the virtual machine; from the virtual machine window: its path is shown in View -> Details -> IDE Disk1 -> Source Path. Make (as root) a copy of the `.qcow2` file somewhere else and change its owner to your normal user with `chown`, then pass it as the `-hda` argument to the `qemu` command as given in my example. If you want to trial stuff without making permanent changes, add the `-snapshot` option to `qemu`. You can also make disk images that include only the differences with `qemu-img create -b base.qcow2 diff.qcow2`.

Comment: If you want to create a virtual machine without the whole `libvirt` complication, it's very easy: `qemu-img create hda.qcow2 15G`. Then install an OS on it with: `qemu-system-x86_64 -enable-kvm ... ... -hda hda.qcow2 -cdrom install_disk.iso`. You could then import the hda.qcow2 with `virt-manager` if you ever want to.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way is to remove the default gateway from the windows machine settings. That will remove the default route and will only be able to access the "local network". You may need to do the same for both IPv4 and IPv6 and disable any automatic address acquisition method.

Comment: Almost. Remove the default gw from the guest OS and specify a route to a specific subnet to allow the guest to access LAN resources.  You (probably) don't want to also block the host (plus any other guests, etc).

Comment: @ivanivan He only asked about access to the host

Comment: @V13: Thanks for your answer! So you mean in machine settings I should add a network interface first - hereby: Which network source, which MAC address and which device model should I select?

Comment: @V13 So it would be a very small subnet or just the specific host.  Either way, no default route, route to resource desired, done.  No messing around on host needed.

Comment: @Dave setup the windows box as if you'd set it up with network connectivity, then change the ip address assignment to be static and add an IP address from the correct address and the default mask, but don't add a default gateway. Since you don't want internet access, you shouldn't probably add a DNS either.

Comment: @V13: I am very sorry, I am a bit confused. You said: "then change the ip address assignment to be static and add an IP address from the correct address and the default mask, but don't add a default gateway." In `virt-manager`, where can I change all those settings you mentioned?

Comment: @Dave Those are the plain Windows settings that you need to set. You don't need to change anything in virt-manager