# QEMU: How to set up SSH File Exchange (SFTP) between Linux Host and Windows Guest?

Tags: windows, virtual-machine, qemu, sftp

Assumed I run a isolated virtual network bridge without public internet access (based on [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/475719/241507) solution):

**How can I set up a SFTP file exchange (e.g. via WinSCP) between guest machine and host machine successfully?**

So far I've tried that:

1. Install WinSCP/FileZilla in Windows guest
2. Connect WinSCP/FileZilla to IP-address of the host machine, but hereby I don't receive any connection.

In WinSCP/FileZilla, do I have to connect to real hosts IP address to reach its target directories or do I have to use some different IP address?

Host is Debian Stretch, guest is Windows 10.

Comment: Like I said in that answer, you have to use the host's IP address for that virtual network interface. You won't be able to use other IP addresses on the host.

Comment: @MichaelHampton: You mean, when assigning the desired IPv4 configuration to the virtual network bridge, I have to choose hosts IP address as the network bridge IP?

Comment: No, the isolated virtual network has its own range of IP addresses, and you must use only those.